# sas ods --> ppt always 'Repair Message'

Tags: sas, powerpoint, enterprise-guide

I always get the following message when opening a ppt which I modified with SAS before:
[image]

> Translation: PowerPoint has recognized a Probelm with the content of
>   test2.pptx. PowerPoint can try to repair the presentation. If you
>   trust the source click 'Repair'

Example based on SASHELP library

```
ods powerpoint file="\\<serverlocation>\test2.pptx" ;

proc sgplot data=sashelp.prdsale;
vbar product / response=actual stat=sum group=year nostatlabel
       groupdisplay=cluster dataskin=gloss;
xaxis display=(nolabel);
yaxis grid;
run;

ods _all_ close;
```

After repairing the ppt it seems fine. Any ideas why this pops up and how to prevent it?

**I am using excel in German and SAS in English**

[image]

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? PPT is relatively new and I wonder if your version was still test. I get no errors in SAS 9.4 TS1M5 using Office 2010.

Comment: sas enterprise guide 7.1. Is that enough for version info?

Comment: No, the SAS version is needed. Use `proc product_status;run;` and check the log for your version. Should be something similar to what I included in my post.

Comment: Okay thanks. How about 9.4_M5 ?

Comment: That's the latest version. My other thought is it's clear you're writing to a server and then download the file somehow? I wonder if that's happening correctly. Can you try ftping the file with a binary method to see if it still generates an error. Otherwise it points to a setting you have set, which means your best bet is to work with SAS tech support to debug this.

Comment: sorry, i don't have an ftp client on the company pc. I tried saving on different servers, result is identical... Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: I tried running this on SAS Studio which outputs to a unix server and testing it and it worked fine, no errors. Consider trying to modify your style and see if that changes anything? Otherwise, since its not replicable, your best bet is to contact SAS Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

swap out:
/*ods _all_ close;*/

with:
ods powerpoint close;

reboot and run that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your answer and include some code formatting to improve its readability. You can enclose code snippets between ` characters or select a code snippet and press Ctrl+K to format the selection.